# Velocity - random number generation in a template

Tags: templates, random, velocity

I'd like to assign a random value to a variable in a velocity template.

However this code:

```
#set ($random = $math.getRandom())
```

returns:

```
java.util.Random@5706937e
```

How to obtain this value or assign a random value to a variable in a different way from within a velocity template?

Comment: Does the getRandom() method return an object ? Change the return type of the method to int and then check again.

Comment: adding `int` does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Velocity 1.7 from [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7):

```
#set ($random = $math.getRandom())
```

and in VM file use:

```
#set($mathTool = $serviceLocator.findService("org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.MathTool"))
```

Range from 1 to 20:

```
#set($my_rnd=$mathTool.random(1,20))
```

or range from 0 to 1:

```
#set($my_rnd=$mathTool.getRandom())
```